# separate movement in sql row

Tags: sql, sql-server

hello i need help how to make a view, and i am a newbie in sql ..
I have a table containing inventory movements, the columns are

> idItem | idDepositOrigin | idDepositDestination | quantity

I need to make a query that returns 2 rows of that movement separated by deposit and that the amount for the origin deposit is negative

> idItem  | deposit_Id (origin)      | (- quantity)

---

> idItem  | deposit_Id (Destination) | (quantity  )

This table should have about 1 million records and with which the stock will be calculated, I need it to be fast, otherwise it should save in a table with double entry, that's what I try to avoid ...
I have made a union, but I have doubts if it is the best way to do it

```
select mov.idItem, deposit.id, (mov.quantity * -1) quantity
from dbo.inv_movement mov
left join dbo.inv_deposits deposit on deposit.id = mov.idDepositOrigin

Union

select mov.idItem, deposit.id, (mov.quantity) quantity
from dbo.inv_movement mov
left join dbo.inv_deposits deposit on deposit.id = mov.idDepositDestination
```

the expected result

[image]

Comment: Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, do you think that using a union all is a good idea for this case? Do you think it would not affect the performance of the query very much in a large amount of data? I ask because I do not have much experience with it ...

Comment: @FabianWesling A million rows is not really a lot of data. Not sure how "fast" you need the query to be, but I can't imagine this taking more than a few seconds.

Comment: @FabianWesling Also, why are you joining on deposits table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you'd simply be better off using `VALUES` to create 2 rows per row:

```
select mov.idItem, deposit.id, V.quantity
from dbo.inv_movement mov
     left join dbo.inv_deposits deposit on deposit.id = mov.idDepositOrigin
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(mov.quantity * -1),(mov.quantity))V(quantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are, at least from your desired output, performing an unnecessary join.

```
select mov.idItem, mov.idDepositOrigin, (mov.quantity * -1) quantity
from dbo.inv_movement mov
Union
select mov.idItem, mov.idDepositDestination, (mov.quantity) quantity
from dbo.inv_movement mov
```

If you wanted to ensure that they are in the same order, you could revise it as:

```
select * from(
    select mov.idItem, 'Origin' as Source, mov.idDepositOrigin, (mov.quantity * -1) quantity
    from dbo.inv_movement mov
    Union
    select mov.idItem, 'Destination', mov.idDepositDestination, (mov.quantity) quantity
    from dbo.inv_movement mov
)c
order by idItem, Source desc
```

Unfortunately, the image server is blocked on my work network, so if there's something else in your image that I'm missing, I apologize